# How to send a 1kb size message java

Tags: java

how can i send a 1kb message in java, i am trying to send a message from one machine to another, of a fixed size 1kb, how can this be achieved ?

currently i am able to send messages such as "test" between the machines, but ideally i want to be able to send a fixed size message of 1kb

this is how i am currently sending test

```
   if (myrank == 0) {
    char[] mess = " test ".toCharArray();
    MPI.COMM_WORLD.Send(mess, 0, mess.length, MPI.CHAR, 1, 99);
}
```

Currently this is how am i sending messages between machines :

```
import mpi.* ;

class Hello {

  static public void main(String[] args) {
    MPI.Init(args);
int myrank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Rank();
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
if (myrank == 0) {
    char[] mess = " test ".toCharArray();
    MPI.COMM_WORLD.Send(mess, 0, mess.length, MPI.CHAR, 1, 99);
} else {
    char[] mess = new char[20];
    MPI.COMM_WORLD.Recv(mess, 0, 20, MPI.CHAR, 0, 99);
    System.out.println("received:" + new String(mess));
}

long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long duration = endTime - startTime;
System.out.println(duration);
    MPI.Finalize();
  }
}
```

would a byte array be a good solution ?

need fixed size messages, to help benchmark results for example i am looking to compare the increase in time taken to send a 1kb message, 1mb, 20mb ........ 1gb etc

EDIT :

would this work ? would this send 8 bits ?

```
int i = 10;  

String text = String.format("%08d", i);  
// text now contains "00000010"  
// 8 bits
```

Comment: Could you please add why you need a fixed size?

Comment: Indeed. This sounds like an XY problem

Comment: fixed sizes are needed for me to benchmark ping times between machines, ideally it increasing in size

Comment: And where is exactly your problem? If you already can send messages, why cannot these message have any size you you want within clever limits? 1 Kb does not look like a lot.

Comment: i am un sure how to send messages with limits, i want to send 1kb then 1mb, etc just so i can measure the increase of time with the increase of message size

Comment: You've posted the (nearly) same question twice within five minutes?

Comment: yes but this question i just want to learn how to send a fixed message, the other was about a fixed sized message increasing, but currently only looking to send a fixed size message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send a 1kb message, create a message of size 1kb and send it.

```
import mpi.* ;

class Hello {

    static public void main(String[] args) {

        MPI.Init(args);
        int myrank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Rank();
        int tag = 99;

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (myrank == 0) {
            char[] mess = new char [1024];
            MPI.COMM_WORLD.Send(mess, 0, mess.length, MPI.CHAR, 1, tag);
        } else if (myrank == 1) {
            char[] mess = new char[1024];
            MPI.COMM_WORLD.Recv(mess, 0, 1024, MPI.CHAR, 0, tag);
            System.out.println("received:" + new String(mess));
        }

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long duration = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println(duration);
        MPI.Finalize();
    }
}
```

Better still, measure ping-pong latency, which is better defined (round-trip return time), and use several lengths:

```
import mpi.* ;

class Hello {

    static public void main(String[] args) {

        MPI.Init(args);
        int myrank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Rank();
        int tag = 99;
        int maxlen = 512*1024*1024;
        int minlen = 64;
        char [] sendbuff = new char [maxlen];
        char [] recvbuff = new char [maxlen];


        if (myrank == 0) {
            for (int len = minlen; len < maxlen; len *= 4) {
                long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();                    
                 MPI.COMM_WORLD.Send(sendbuff, 0, len, MPI.CHAR, 1, tag);
                 MPI.COMM_WORLD.Recv(recvbuff, 0, len, MPI.CHAR, 1, tag);
                long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long duration = endTime - startTime;
                System.out.println("Ping-pong time for " + len + " is " + duration);
            }
        } else if (myrank == 1) {
            for (int len = minlen; len < maxlen; len *= 4) {
                 MPI.COMM_WORLD.Recv(recvbuff, 0, len, MPI.CHAR, 0, tag);
                 MPI.COMM_WORLD.Send(recvbuff, 0, len, MPI.CHAR, 0, tag);
            }
        }


        MPI.Finalize();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) on the sending (initiating) side and [ServerSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) on the receiving (listening for the message) side. Socket allows to open output stream and ServerSocket can spawn another Socket where you can open input stream. It is not much different if the message is fixed size or not.

You can also use SOAP, RMI, Protocol Buffers, CORBA, MPI and the like, google. These will add more complexity but also functionality and each is strong in its application area.